# Does the saveAsTextFile create the directories?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Does `saveAsTextFile` create the directories, if I am saving a text file and directory or path on a Linux machine does not exist?  Would the below Scala code create the `test1` directory if it is not there?

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile ("file:///test1/textfile.txt");
```

Comment: Ok, that is good to know.  A follow-up:  saveAsTextFile creates multiple parts for a file, so you end of multiple files.  These files that I am dealilng with are small.  How to turn that feature off?  Is there another function that just saves RDDs as text files?

Comment: Use `rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(...)`, this will put the data into a single partition and will therefore save it in single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes - as a quick test of the code you pasted shows. 
Of course, the user must have the necessary permissions to create the directory.